# Spring security with user XML configuration does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Spring security with user XML configuration does not work

I have a project with Spring Security with a user configured in the xml and do not work for me, I have done more to test small projects but this time does not work and I do not know why. The urls are properly protected but I fail to login. The result is always "error". Always redirects to "/login.html?error" although the username and password are correct.

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>foo Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <tiles.version>3.0.4</tiles.version>
    </properties>  

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>    
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>               

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>   

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>5.1.32</version>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>4.2.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
           <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
           <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.55</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>                               

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>foo</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>    
  </build>
</project>
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.foo.controladores, com.company.foo.servicio, com.company.foo.fachada, com.company.foo.dao" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <!-- Tiles Configuration --> 
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/templates.xml</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/equipo-tiles.xml</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/jugador-tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Tiles View Url Based Resolver -->
    <bean id="tilesViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
           <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    </bean>

    <!-- css y js -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />

</beans>
```

My web.xml:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">      

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>foo-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>foo-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener> 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/foo-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            classpath:hibernate4Config.xml,
            classpath:spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>   

</web-app>
```

My spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jugadores**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jugadores/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/equipos**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/equipos/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />      
        <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login.html" 
            default-target-url="/jugadores.html" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.html?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
          <user-service>
            <user name="root" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
          </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final ModelAndView printLogin(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) final String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) final String logout) 
    {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("login");

        if (error != null) {
            view.addObject("error", "Error");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            view.addObject("msg", "Exit");
        }       

        return view;
    }   
}
```

And my login page:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/includes/taglibs.jsp"%>
<div class="wrapper">
  <form class="form-signin" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method="POST">

    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
      <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
      <div class="error">${error}</div>
    </c:if>

    <h4 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h4>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='j_username' placeholder="Login" /> 
        <br />
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name='j_password' placeholder="Password" />
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">OK</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I can not find anywhere what fails me.

Comment: What's the error?  Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: The result is always "/login.html?error" although the username and password are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your jsp/html input filed names does not match the parameter names expected/configured by/for spring security.

In your jsp you use the (default) names `j_username` and `j_username` but you configured spring security to use `username` and `password`

So change your configuration to use `j_username` and `j_username` instead :

```
<form-login 
        login-page="/login.html" 
        default-target-url="/jugadores.html" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error" 
        username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_username" />
```

Comment: In principle it would make sense, but does not solve my problem. In the first instance use the same names but not the second, suppose it's a mistake, http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/  http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-custom-login-form-annotation-example/

Comment: What do you mean be first and second instance?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. I changed versions of the XML schemas.

In my dispatcher.xml I changed::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
```

and in my spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
```